# How do I use new google identity JS library to work with sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api-js-client, google-identity

Google introduced new Sign In JS library(`gsi`) a long time ago but Google Sheets documentation still shows examples using `gapi`. What would be the best approach to combine/replace gapi with gsi? May I have an example?

Comment: Did you see this? https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration

Comment: @Wakka Of course. I have no problems using new gsi library. I'd like to know how to use gsi with Sheets API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Update 2022/02/04:

Documentation regarding [Google Identity Services JavaScript SDK](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/overview) just became available.

In contrast with [Sign In With Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview), which only handles authentication (see [Authentication and authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration#authentication_and_authorization)), this library handles OAuth tokens (see [Using the token model](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-token-model)) to access Google APIs, and so can be used as a complete replacement to `gapi`.

Please notice though that `GIS` doesn't handle calling the API, and so Google suggests to keep using `gapi.client` for that ([ref](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#libraries_and_modules)):

> You can safely continue using the gapi.client module from the Google API Client Library for JavaScript, and take advantage of its automatic creation of callable JS methods from a discovery document, batching multiple API calls, and CORS management functionality.

So, after getting the access token via `GIS`, you can either use `gapi` to call the API, or call the API without any of these libraries (in the example below and in the official docs, [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) is used for that).

#### Sample 1: Use Google Identity Services:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="initClient()" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var client;
      var access_token;

      function initClient() {
        client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
          client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',
          scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly',
          callback: (tokenResponse) => {
            access_token = tokenResponse.access_token;
          },
        });
      }
      function getToken() {
        client.requestAccessToken();
      }
      function revokeToken() {
        google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(access_token, () => {console.log('access token revoked')});
      }
      function listMajors() {
        var spreadsheetId = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms';
        var range = 'Class Data!A2:E';
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
          }
        };
        xhr.open('GET', `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadsheetId}/values/${range}`);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);
        xhr.send();
      }
    </script>
    <h1>Google Identity Services Authorization Token model</h1>
    <button onclick="getToken();">Get access token</button> <br><br>
    <button onclick="listMajors();">Call Sheets API</button> <br><br>
    <button onclick="revokeToken();">Revoke token</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Sample 2. Use GIS in combination with GAPI:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisInit()" async defer></script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoad()" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>

    var tokenClient;
    var access_token;

    function gapiStart() {
        gapi.client.init({
      }).then(function() {
        gapi.client.load('sheets', 'v4');
      }).then(function(response) {
        console.log('discovery document loaded');
      }, function(reason) {
        console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
      });
    }

    function gapiLoad() {
      gapi.load('client', gapiStart)
    }

    function gisInit() {
      tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly',
        callback: (tokenResponse) => {
          access_token = tokenResponse.access_token;
        },
      });
    }

    function getToken() {
      tokenClient.requestAccessToken();
    }

    function listMajors() {
      gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId: '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms',
        range: 'Class Data!A2:E',
      }).then(function(response) {
        var range = response.result;
        console.log(range);
      });
    }


    function revokeToken() {
      google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(access_token, () => {console.log('access token revoked')});
    }

  </script>

  <h1>Google Identity Services Authorization and GAPI</h1>
  <button onclick="getToken();">Get access token</button> <br><br>
  <button onclick="listMajors();">Call Sheets API</button> <br><br>
  <button onclick="revokeToken();">Revoke token</button>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Note:

Both these samples are based on the examples found in the official docs, in which Calendar API is called (see [Implicit flow examples](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#implicit_flow_examples)).

#### Reference:

- [Google Identity Services JavaScript SDK](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/overview)
- [Migrate to Google Identity Services](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis)

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Doing `gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);` will initiate library(not the user) authentication/authorization again.
What I can see from the code example is that gsi will provide general user authentication and then, gapi will catch the sessions loaded by gsi. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @Kostiantyn `What I can see from the code example is that gsi will provide general user authentication and then, gapi will catch the sessions loaded by gsi. Do I understand it correctly?` Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks @lamblichus, I got your point, but I think it's still quite stupid for Google to force customers to use old library. Is there any other way to use Sheets API without using gapi?

Comment: @Kostiantyn You can always go through OAuth and call the API without using any library https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#oauth-2.0-endpoints, but I'm not sure what would be the point of that, as long as `gapi` is available. `gapi` is still the current official library to access Google APIs client-side, this fact doesn't change with the existence of `gsi`, since `gsi` cannot be used for that. Whether this will change in the future is anyone's guess, but that's how things stand nowadays.

Comment: Dear, @Iamblichus. I really appreciate your effort trying to help me, but I'm not sure accepting the answer is the right option because it doesn't completely solve the problem. It's more like a workaround rather than a proper solution. Accepting it might deceive other users. I upvoted it though. I might need to read the rules.

Comment: @Kostiantyn When the goal is impossible, an answer cannot have a "solution", just workarounds. "It cannot be done" can be an answer. `gsi` cannot be used to access Sheets API, pure and simple.

Comment: Sorry to barge in, but I am very confused about the whole `gapi` deprecation and new `gsi` and google directed me to this thread... As far as I understood, `gapi` `auth` and all related methods are supposed to be deprecated soon, that said, I thought we would have to migrate over to the new `gsi` but from what I read here, it is not possible and it is also an intentional behaviour? In that case, we will necessarily have to use deprecated library? [1]

Comment: [2] Also, I came here because of gPicker api, in there we must use a authToken, but JWT provided by `gsi` does not contain said token, from this example, there is also no token involved... will `gapi` automagically get the token from sessions loaded by `gsi`? If so, we will be *required* to use their button? Because as far I got from the docs, there's no way to do it behind the scenes anymore... we need to use google's button

Comment: I currently have this opened with google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217414937 to see if I could get better doc, but so far I didn't get a good answer on to how to integrate picker with `gsi` :(

Comment: @Kostiantyn I updated my answer, I hope this is useful to you.

Comment: @Gabrielle I updated my answer, I hope this is useful to you. Also, I think it's only `platform` that is getting deprecated, not all `gapi`.

Comment: @lamblichus Thank you so much, that really helped!! But not sure why I still feel this is kinda old, first time I tried integrating the new Identity with picker, they would show a single button very fancy, now it looks exactly like the old way haha
Also, somehow google created a whole new service but didn't address the fact that the sign in doesn't work without third-party cookies (not even through a warning on the screen)

Comment: @lamblichus Thanks. It looks very solid now. I've accepted the answer. Great job, mate.

Answer (score 2):

As addition to [Iamblichus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10612011/iamblichus) answer, you can save `access_token` and use it with `setToken` method.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisInit()" async defer></script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoad()" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>

    var tokenClient;
    var access_token;

    function gapiStart() {
        gapi.client.init({
      }).then(function() {
        **if (access_token)**
            **gapi.auth.setToken({access_token: access_token})**
        gapi.client.load('sheets', 'v4');
      }).then(function(response) {
        console.log('discovery document loaded');
      }, function(reason) {
        console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
      });
    }

    function gapiLoad() {
      gapi.load('client', gapiStart)
    }

    function gisInit() {
      tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly',
        callback: (tokenResponse) => {
          access_token = tokenResponse.access_token;
          **window.localStorage.setItem("gtoken", tokenResponse.access_token);**
        },
      });
    }

    function getToken() {
      tokenClient.requestAccessToken();
    }

    function listMajors() {
      gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId: '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms',
        range: 'Class Data!A2:E',
      }).then(function(response) {
        var range = response.result;
        console.log(range);
      });
    }


    function revokeToken() {
      google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(access_token, () => {console.log('access token revoked')});
    }
    **if (window.localStorage.getItem("gtoken"))**
        **access_token = window.localStorage.getItem("gtoken")**

  </script>

  <h1>Google Identity Services Authorization and GAPI</h1>
  <button onclick="getToken();">Get access token</button> <br><br>
  <button onclick="listMajors();">Call Sheets API</button> <br><br>
  <button onclick="revokeToken();">Revoke token</button>
</body>
</html>
```